# viv.self does not define "profile"

Tags: bixby

what does this error message mean?

Line 35:5'viv.self' does not define 'profile'

capsule.bxb:

```
 permissions {
    library-permission (contact:contacts)
    library-permission (self:profile)
    device-location-access
  }
```

Does it mean there has to be a Profile concept?

Comment: can you include the code with import part?

Answer (score 0):

Please use an updated version 4.0.1.

[image]

Please also add code to capsule-info.bxb as step 3 in https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/developers/library.self